# c++ - writing to a output file from diffrent cpp files

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

We have three diffrenet .cpp files.
when i make a file in random.cpp

```
    ofstream outfile ("random.log");
```

Then I write to the file random.log in the random.cpp file:

```
    outfile << " something" ;
```

Then i go to a diffrent .cpp file like StudentCS.cpp there I open the file using:

```
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("random.log",std::ios_base::app);
```

It will write all of the StudentCS output after all of the random.cpp output even if I call StudentCS in the middle of random.cpp. I am trying to wrtie from random.cpp then it calls StudentCS.cpp which should write something then back to random.cpp which writes again

Answer (score 1):

Open the file once, then pass the stream object around. Or better: make the logger object available to any module that needs logging.

Comment: Yes. And depending on who is responsible for file writes, it may be worth looking at a dependency model or a singleton model to control the lifetime of the open file.

Answer (score 0):

random.cpp

```
void studentCS(ofstream & outfile);
void random() {
   ofstream outfile ("random.log");
   outfile << " something" ;
   outfile.close();
   studentCS(outfile);
   outfile.open("random.log",std::ios_base::app);
   outfile << " something write after call to studenCS";
}
```

studentCS.cpp

```
void studentCS(ofstream & outfile) {
   ofstream outfile("random.log",std::ios_base::app);
   outfile << " something else ";
}
```

But keep in mind that you should try to avoid as much as you can open/close operation, which are heavy on CPU.

Comment: In random.cpp calls a teach function that calls a study function that is in StudentCS I don't want to send the file around I just want to open it in the other .cpp file and write to it

Comment: Then just close it before calling your other function, and re-open it with append flag after that.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using the name "random.log".

Does this imply that you are writing a log file? If so, you could consider using one of many logging classes developed to make this process easier (see [1](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/logging-in-c/201804215), [2](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/), [3](http://tomicki.net/clog.php), [4](http://ahm507.blogspot.de/2006/12/simplest-logging-class-in-c.html), [5](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1304)).

Another thought...

You are opening and closing your file in different parts of the project. Other answers have suggested passing a file pointer around. But if you really need to write to this file from everywhere and take the proper precautions, you could consider using a global variable here.